# Consulta llamar datos seleccionando un campo AJAX datatable

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

Hola tengo la siguiente duda llamo los datos de mi base de datos mediante el año actual,con el siguiente código:

```js
 <script>  
      $(document).on("ready", function(){
       listar();
      });
      
      var listar = function(){
       var table = $("#dt_cliente").DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "destroy": true,
        "ajax":{
         "method": "POST",
         "url" : "inc/listar.php"
        },
        "columns":[
         {"data":"decreto"},
         {"data":"anno"},
         {"data":"materia"}
         ],
         
         
       });

      }
      
     </script>
```

```html
<?php

 include 'conexion.php';
  $anno=date("Y");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM decreto WHERE fecha='$anno' ORDER BY decreto_id ASC;";

 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
 

 if (!$resultado) {
 die("Error");
 }else {
  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
   $arreglo["data"][] =  $data;
  }
  echo json_encode($arreglo);
 }
 mysqli_free_result($resultado);
 mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Mi pregunta seria si en el HTML deseo seleccionar una fecha distinta y que me carguen los datos en el datatable con dicha fecha. Espero ser claro cualquier pregunta estaré al tanto del post. Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enviale la fecha por la url y de esa fecha obtienes el año y haces el filtro en el sql:

```
var listar = function(año){
                var table = $("#dt_cliente").DataTable({
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    "destroy": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        "method": "POST",
                        "url" : "inc/listar.php?anno=" + año// enviamos la fecha
                    },
                    "columns":[
                        {"data":"decreto"},
                        {"data":"anno"},
                        {"data":"materia"}
                        ],


                });

            }
```

Ahora en el php, obtienes el parametro  utilizando `$_GET["anno"]`:

```
<?php

    include 'conexion.php';

     // converti
    $anno= $_GET["anno"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM decreto WHERE fecha='$anno' ORDER BY decreto_id ASC;";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    //...
    mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Entoneces para cargar los datos solo tendrias que obtener el valor del `select` y pasarlo como parametro al metodo `listar`:

```
var $select = $("#id-select").change(function(){
  // esta funcion se ejecuta cuando se cambie el año
  var anno = $select.val(); // obtenemos el valor
  listar(anno);// cargamos la lista
});
// cargamos el año por defecto
var anno = $select.val();
listar(anno);
```

Comment: una consulta en la linea 
"url" : "inc/listar.php?fecha=" + fecha // enviamos la fecha
si tengo un <select> </select> con los años que deseo filtran como los puedo pasar al +fecha

Comment: Solo vas a enviar el año?

Comment: Al cargar la pagina deseo que busque por la fecha actual y dentro del HTML un <select> </select> con los años de búsqueda y al momento de seleccionar uno de esos años cargue la información que tengo ingresada en ese año en el datatable

Comment: Al seleccionar un año del select no me carga dicho año se queda en la primera opción

Comment: Simplemente agregale un evento change al select para que siempre que cambie el valor, se ejecute el metodo listar(). Mira la respuesta actualizada

Comment: Funciona de maravilla. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo te lo agradezco mucho :)

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente tienes que crear un FORM en tu HTML, para que mandes un $_POST o $_GET a tu archivo php, para que tu archivo PHP haga la busqueda de acuerdo a la fecha que se envie desde el HTML.

Algo asi:

```
    <?php
        include 'conexion.php';
//En vez de declarar una variable año, la recogeremos con un $_POST
            //$anno=date("Y");
$anno = $_POST['fecha']; //que viene desde tu form en HTML
        $query = "SELECT * FROM decreto WHERE fecha='$anno' ORDER BY decreto_id ASC;";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);


        if (!$resultado) {
        die("Error");
        }else {
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                $arreglo["data"][] =  $data;
            }
            echo json_encode($arreglo);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
```

Y el form va algo asi

```
    <form id="reportes">
      <div class="container" style="margin-top: 5px;"> 
        <div class="row">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" id="cuerpo">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">Escriba los parametros para la busqueda</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                  <label for="Estado" class="control-label">Fecha                 </div>
              <select class="target">
                 <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
                 <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="text-center">

            <button type="button" id="reporte" class="btn btn-primary">Generar Reporte</button>
            <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Nueva Consulta</button>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid" id="respuesta"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Coloco dos fechas por si quieres filtrar entre fechas
 Tu peticion ajax iria algo asi,

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
var listar = function(){
                var table = $("#dt_cliente").DataTable({
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    "destroy": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        "method": "POST",
                        "url" : "inc/listar.php"
                    },
                    "columns":[
                        {"data":"decreto"},
                        {"data":"anno"},
                        {"data":"materia"}
                        ],


                });



    }
```

});

Comment: Al cargar la pagina deseo que busque por la fecha actual y dentro del HTML un <select> </select> con los años de búsqueda y al momento de seleccionar uno de esos años cargue dicha información en el datatable

Comment: Entonces en vez del input pon el select, y puedes usar jquery para detectar el cambio (.change()) para enviar la peticion si se cambia el select

Comment: Si solo quieres filtrar en el DataTable te dejo un [ejemplo que te pueda interesar](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) @MoteCL

Comment: Gracias por la información @Luis Fernando